# How to block not defined server_name in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have two `server {}` blocks with the domains I need to use.

But I have found a problem..... if I configure the DNS of another domain that point to my server, nginx response correctly! Why?

Nginx should response with a http Error! but it returns the website that have the same IP address, why? I don't have a server name with that domain!

Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

It responds because you don't have a separate 'default' vhost configured.  There is always a default, or fallback, vhost configured, so that nginx knows what to do in the event it gets a request of the type you've sent.

The [nginx documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_name) provides a good description of how the server-name-to-vhost-matching is performed, but in short I'd recommend configuring a new vhost like this:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  root /usr/share/empty;
}
```

(You may have to create `/usr/share/empty` if it doesn't already exist)

This will simply serve an empty directory to anyone who hits your server with an unrecognized vhost name.  You can get fancier with various sorts of error pages and whatnot if you like.

Comment: `root /usr/share/empty;` can be replaced with `return 404;`

Comment: That you can.  Good tip!